# Insert list<> content into SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have some functions in my code, that returns a list with some items.
I need to insert into SQL each list component in different lines, but actually dont know how.

Anyone can help it? I'll leave the code below

```
string RecursosInfra = "Email, Impressao, Desktop";
string[] recurso = Regex.Split(RecursosInfra, @"\W+");

List<string> ListaRecursosInfra = new List<string>();

foreach (string valor in recurso)
{
    ListaRecursosInfra.Add(valor);
}
```

To insert common values into my SQL DB, i use something like this in DAL Layer:

```
string id;
AbriConexao();
Tr = Con.BeginTransaction();

String query =
    "INSERT INTO[dbo].[TI01A]" +
    "  ([Name]    " +
    "  ,[Age])            " +
    " VALUES                       " +
    "  (@Name     " +
    "  ,@Age);             " +
    "  SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()";

//string insertedID = dbcm.ExecuteScalar();
//// This will insert the record and also get the id of the inserted record in database

Cmd = new SqlCommand(query, Con, Tr);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", s.Name);
Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", s.Age);

id = Cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
//Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

Tr.Commit();

return id;
```

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Can you please edit your post to demonstrate what you have tried so far?

Comment: No. Pure SQL query

Comment: Can you show us your table or stored procedure that you try to call? Or even more, the parameters you need to add? Here you don't explain what you try to do and what you need. Don't forget to edit your post to make it more clear for us.

Comment: Edited with the code i used to insert on DB

Comment: You are not clear! Tell us what exactly you want to do and give us the real code you use. We don't want you to post an kind of code you want, we want you to post what you've already tried to do

Comment: This doesn't look like all of the relevant code. I see a List<string> but don't see any objects with Name and Age properties..

Comment: @MarkC. That's it, he doesn't show us the real part of code that cause an issue, or even more what he already tried to do... He really needs to be clearful about what he wants..

Comment: @taktak That's OK - we can help guide them through how to format and ask the right question so we don't run into this in the future

Comment: My form returns something like "Item, Item2, Item3" to the model. I need to get this model value and insert each one in DB, but dont know how do it.

Comment: I agree, let's guide them :)

Comment: @HudsonMedeiros So you need to loop over your list and add each one to an SqlParameter of a stored procedure?

Comment: @taktak Exactly! Each list component will be added separately on a different table (TI02)